# SiteEdit not enabled when opening a popup window

Tags: siteedit, siteedit-2009

I have a SiteEdit enabled site that has a link which opens as a new popup.

```html
<a href="http://dev.upgrade.mysite.com:84/popups/privacy.aspx?__Proxy=0" target="_self">
  <span>Privacy</span>
</a>
```

(please note that the `__Proxy` query string parameter is added by SiteEdit on the anchor URL)

The issue we are facing is that SiteEdit is not enabled on the popup.

When I remove `?__Proxy=0` from the URL by editing the HTML in the browser, SiteEdit works fine. I would like to know if this is a restriction from SiteEdit or if there is any workaround for this?

We are using SiteEdit 2009 SP3.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it opens as a new popup? From the HTML you posted, it is opening in the current frame - which means that it the __Proxy=0 parameter is correct (otherwise you would get multiple of the SiteEdit headers).